# Apps Startup on Power Up

Tags: applications

When I turn my phone on, many apps also turn on in the background. This slows down my phone. How do I shut them down? Why is the OS built this way? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Re: "Why is the OS built this way", it's the same as startup on other OSes like Windows, so it makes sense. The only "nonsense" is why the OS doesn't provide startup configuration, which might be valid to some users. But then, how do you know that "many apps start-up on boot"? And how do you know which are important and which are not?

Answer (score 0):

The apps which start automatically with your phone have it in their permissions to start together. Apps like Messengers need to start with your phone so as to be able to run in the background and show latest messages received etc.

You can try an app called Greenify(which can hibernate apps in the background or permanently). Give [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/198135/how-to-optimize-your-android-phones-battery-life-using-greenify/) a read.

Answer (score 0):

There are valid reasons why some apps need to start at bootup, but the honest answer why many apps do this is that the developers don't think that maybe you have 100 other apps installed that also want to run at bootup.  You're right, it slows everything down.

The most valid reason to run at boot time is to execute a process that always needs to be running, such as an antivirus program.

The not-so-wonderful reasons are to track your habits for marketing or to display advertisements.  Another unfortunate reason is to pre-load some part of the app so that it *appears* to load faster the first time; the reality, of course, is that the device still needs to spend time performing this operation and thus it can make bootups take an unreasonable amount of time (especially if more than one app is performing this undesirable practice).

The easiest way to stop apps from running on boot is to use a program like Autostarts [available on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repo/com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts_31.apk) and [on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) (to help support the development), or Startup Manager [available on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager).

The trouble with blocking an app from running on boot is that you don't know what it was really doing.  It might be nothing, or it could be database maintenance that, if never performed, could result in a corrupt or bloated database for that application.  There is always a little gamble involved.

Another option is to use a program like Greenify [available on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) which can be configured to temporarily hibernate applications when they are not in immediate use.  Support for Greenify is [available on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/greenify).

The best practice for developers is to never have their application start on bootup unless it is essential.  A second choice is to make it a user-configurable option.  In either case, the developer should publicly document exactly why the app needs to start at boot and exactly what the consequences are of disabling that option.

Users can voice their concerns directly to the company that developed the app that starts on boot and by choosing to not support applications that unnecessarily start on boot.